# Firefox and other non-gtk applications do not adopt gtk theme

Tags: 22.04, firefox, themes, gtk, gtk3

I applied a GTK 3.20 [theme by EliverLara github repo](https://github.com/EliverLara/Nordic) following all the instructions. The theme was applied, but Firefox, and probably other non-GTK apps, do not adopt this theme.

[image: Firefox not working in Nordic theme]

EliverLara also has a [Firefox Nordic theme designed for Firefox](https://github.com/EliverLara/firefox-nordic-theme), however it is very buggy when I apply it: it doesn't show the max, min buttons and completely breaks up.

Is there any way to force all apps to have the same theme (window buttons like the Nordic theme)?

Answer (score 0):

If you using default Ubuntu Firefox, it's in snap package. For applying GTK theme to "snapped" apps, theme must be packed in such package, installed and connected to FF snap. For expample,

```
snap install numix-gtk-themes
snap connect firefox:gtk-3-themes numix-gtk-themes:gtk-3-themes
```

For Qt apps I wrote in `~/.pam_environment` next line:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME  DEFAULT=gtk2
```

I found `gtk-theme-nordic` snap package, but it was packed in 2020 year.